# .htaccess rewriterule being ignored - tyring to remove dates from WP posts

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Should be a fairly simple procedure.  I've done a fair share of internet searching and can't get the htaccess rewrite to work in /public_html

Using a VPS Apache server, any idea's why?  Thank you in advance!

Trying both the older RedirectMatch 301 and the mod_rewrite RewriteRuleas
(one at a time) as below:

```
# New Post URLs, without dates, requires redirects for old links.
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.url.org/$3
# or RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://www.url.org/$3

 BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([a-z0-9\-/]+)$ /$3 [R=301,NC,L]
etc...
```

Comment: Please include examples of the URLs you want to redirect from/to.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually change them in Settings -> Permalinks and it will change the link that generated for the post. And if you still be unhappy with result you can remove **WordPress rewrite rules** for dates with `date_rewrite_rules` filter.

UPDATE:

In this case, you can use post_rewrite_rules to keep the date to post rule working and implement redirect during `tempalte_redirect` action-hook. You can plug this code into your codebase and flush rewrite rules in WordPress. Should work right after that.

```
add_filter( 'post_rewrite_rules', function( $rules ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $rule = [ '([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$' =>
        'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]' ];
    return array_merge($rules, $rule);
});

add_filter('template_redirect', function(){
    global $wp_query;

    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $wp_query->get('monthnum') !== "" && $wp_query->get('year') !== "" ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink(), 301 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Settings->Permalinks is already being done but we have to address the posts already created.  The .htaccess URL rewrite is for all the urls already in circulation for existing posts so users don't get a 404 error!   When you say date_rewrite_rules are you talking about hooks located in the WP_Rewrite class in /wp-includes/rewrite.php

Comment: Does the following apply to existing URLs in circulation?
$date_rewrite

    (array) The rewrite rules for date archives.

File: wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the code!  Appreciate the help.  So is this supposed to just go anywhere in /wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php?  It doesn't seem to work.  Do I need to do something special to hit the tempalte_redirect action-hook?  Do I need to put some code in /wp-includes/template-loader.php

Comment: Don't change the wp course code, do your injects via plugin/there wherever it makes more sense. Do some google on how to add your code to functions.php or how to create a simple plugin.

Comment: Thanks again!  Have my first plugin under construction with your 2 methods.  I have another question regarding the plugin not working without errors   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302639/developing-first-plugin-to-rewrite-urls-not-working-no-errors